# To automate user actions, should you leverage a browser automation tool or rely on HTTP requests?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I'd like to scale an infrastructure for automating user actions. I've found tools like [InstaPy](https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py) and [InstaBot](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy) and have seen that one uses a browser automation tool like `Selenium` whereas the other uses only `http requests, etc.`

What are the pros/cons of these various approaches? Which would one be simpler and more cost effective to scale? I assume the `request` approach would be more lean but perhaps a headless approach with testing frameworks could also be as lean?

Comment: How can this question relate to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

User action in the sense means Functional Testing. For Functional Testing, one must go for the real time browser simulation.

On the other hand, there is Performance Testing. To which you need to go with API's(HTTP Requests). Since, API testing is faster than Selenium, your first step is to check with API's to verify whether backend gets broken.

Once API's are passed, we can go ahead with UI/Functional Testing. Both are cost effective, but I would say, Functional Testing is much better, as UI rendering fails often when it comes to Web applications. Functional Testing also tells you whether it is API failure or not for which you can use network traffic logs.